# How can i convert this string to datetime in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a field whose values look like `2017-06-07T12:16:40.000Z`

I have been trying to find any ways to convert it to look like `2017-06-07 12:16`

Comment: To answer the question we also need to know exactly what kind of database you're using, because each database engine does this a little differently. Additionally, I doubt the field really looks like that. If it's a datetime column, what you're seeing is something your database tool shows you for convenience, and the actual value is unreadable binary data.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thank you so much for giving me how to specify my question. below is the current database and language I am working on.          database : AWS athena made of SQL and Hive(maybe) / the data came from flow log of aws VPC. if you need anything else, feel free to give me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This website could be very helpful to you:

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql

For your requirement, you could use:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> MODIFY <column> DATETIME;
```

and then

```
UPDATE <table>
SET column = YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
WHERE <condition>;
```

Hope this helped. Please tell me if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have found the solution for my issue. AWS athen is based on Presto so that you need to follow the syntax and rule of it. the date format above question is based on iso8601. In Presto documentation, you need to use following function, from_iso8601_timestamp(). After that you need to use this function, format_datetime().  it is what i tried and worked that "format_datetime(from_iso8601_timestamp(time), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh')" you can check out functions in Presto documentation, https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html